# Why do forward slashes not need escaping in Sublime Text syntax definition files?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create a new Sublime Text syntax definition for a hobby programming language.

Going through the Ruby and Python bundled syntax definitions I can see that the `first_line_match` regular expressions are:

```
^#!\s*/.*\bpython(\d(\.\d)?)?\b
^#!\s*/.*\bj?ruby\b
```

Pasting these regexes into Rubular or Regex101 gives an error saying that **forwards slashes must be escaped** but they aren't in any of the Sublime Text definitions. Does Sublime Text do this behind the scenes for you?

Comment: It depends on regex engine whether it accepts delimiters or not. Python doesn't. Ruby does.

Answer (score 0):

If `/` is used as the delimiter, then it will need escaped inside so the parser knows the end of the regex is not reached. If the delimiter is something else, then forward slashes don't need escaped. You can see the result of this in the chrome console by creating javascript regex with slash as delimiter, or as string...

n.b. escaping forward slash in string defined regex has no effect

[image]

Comment: I think you’ve nailed it with the “string defined regex”. I guess the parser in ST3 reads the defined regex from the syntax definition file as a string.